# C++: Regex pattern

Tags: c++, regex

I got a regex pattern: (~[A-Z]){10,30} (Thanks to KekuSemau). And I need to edit it, so it will skip 1 letter. So it will be like down below.

```
Input:    CABBYCRDCEBFYGGHQIPJOK 
Output:    A B C D E F G H I J K
```

Comment: Perhaps for that input you could match the first character and capture the second character in a group and replace with a whitespace and the capturing group[`[A-Z]([A-Z])?`](https://regex101.com/r/pNtTia/1)

Comment: What's with the `~`? Just replace `.(.)` with ` $1` (space+$1). [See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/t4ua8x/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Just match two letters each iteration but only capture the second part.

```
(?:~[A-Z](~[A-Z])){5,15}
```

live: https://regex101.com/r/pIAxH8/1

I cut the repetition count (the bit inside the {}'s) by half since the new regex is matching two at a time.

The `?:` in `(?:...)` bit disables capturing of the group.

Answer (score 0):

In regex only, there is no way you can achieve this directly.
**But** you can do this in code:

Use following regex:

```
(.(?<pick>[A-Z]))+
```

and in code make a loop on "captures" of desired group, like in c#:

```
string value = "";
for (int i = 0; i < match.Groups["pick"].Captures.Count; i++)
{
   value = match.Groups["pick"].Captures[0].Value;
}
```